# how to apply jquery code to all LI in a UL

Tags: jquery

Caveat: I am a Wordpress hack, not a front end developer.

A working copy of the code I want to replicate is [here](http://www.orsgroup.com.au/all-states-2/). Note: when you click on the office name, the office details are shown/hidden.

This is the functionality I want to recreate with my own jquery.

I don't know how to use Chrome's developer tools to copy the jquery from the working copy.

I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/npmjud54/8/) of the HTML/CSS.

I need to use jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.viewLocationDetail').click(function() {
    $('.mapLocationDetail').toggle;
  });
}
```

but I need this jquery to be altered so that it applies to all instances of `.viewLocationDetail`, and so that the click only toggles the `.mapLocationDetail` in the same `LI` as the `.viewLocationDetail`.

Example `LI`:

```
<li class="corePrettyStyle prettylink map accredited-training-rto disability-employment-services disability-management-services-dms employment-services employment-support-services-ess job-in-jeopardy training-services wa " data-title="Armadale, WA" data-lat="-32.15511" data-long="116.01419499999997" data-locationindex="0"><a title="View Armadale, WA" href="#" class="viewLocationDetail">Armadale, WA <span class="mapcategories">Categories: <span>Accredited Training – RTO Disability Employment Services Disability Management Services (DMS) Employment Services Employment Support Services (ESS) Job in Jeopardy Training Services WA </span></span></a>
  <div class="mapLocationDetail">
    <div class="mapDescription clearfix">
      <ul class="maploc-des">
        <li>12/47 William Street</li>
        <li>Armadale, WA 6112</li>
        <li><strong>Ph:</strong>&nbsp; (08) 6267 2555</li>
        <li><strong>Fax:</strong> (08) 6267 2556</li>
      </ul>
      For queries not related to Employment Services, please call 1300 677 789.</div>
    <a href="https://staging.orsgroup.com.au/location/armadale-wa/" class="viewLocationPage btn corePrettyStyle">Location &amp; service details</a>
    <div class="getDirections">Get directions from
      <input id="directionsPostcode" type="text" value="" size="10">
      <a href="#" class="getdirections btn corePrettyStyle">go</a>
      <div class="mapLocationDirectionsHolder"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are not from the JavaScript background. Well, there are few mistakes, go ahead and read the comments in the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.viewLocationDetail').click(function() {
    // 1. Use $(this).
    $(this).find('.mapLocationDetail').toggle(); // 2. Missing ()
  });
}); // 3. Missing closing );
```

Comment: For this part: "the click only toggles the .mapLocationDetail in the **same LI** as the .viewLocationDetail."   It's unlikely `.mapLcoationDetail` will be nested inside an `<a>`

Comment: Thanks Praveen. Does this solution work so that only the `.mapLocationDetail` in the same `LI` as the `.viewLocationDetail` is toggled?

Comment: Hi Praveen. I have used the code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/npmjud54/13/), and it is not working?

Comment: @Steve Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: It is in the comment above Praveen. :)

Comment: @Steve Sorry I used my mobile to reply you... Will check it out and let you know... :)

Comment: @Steve The first code I gave worked. Check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a01mh3h8/).